# Performance drop when updating state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building react-native app, but my problem is linked with React itself.

It's an app that connects to external JSON, fetches data, and creates react component for each of item in that JSON data, so it's like 70 child components inside 1 wrapper. App is also using Navigator and phone storage but that's a part of the question.

To visualize:
Parent component (People) has methods to operate on a DB, it fetches data, creates component for each of item in array and exposes methods to child components (Person). Each person has a "add to favourites" button, this is a method updating empty star to full one (conditional rendering) if clicked, updates state of component and whenever local state has been changed it fires parents component to update it's state - and from there parent's component saves all data to DB. So I've made a link to synchronize Child's State -> Parent's State -> Local DB (phone's memory).

Problem is, it's quite slow when updating parent's state. It freezes for 1-1.5 sec. but it's all cool if I remove method to update parent's state (I've marked that in example attached).

Question 1: How to refactor this code to fix performance issue when updating parent's (People's state)?
Question 2: I'm open to any other suggestions and lessons how to improve quality of my code.

Here's a link to visualize my code, I've just removed few non-relevant methods and styles.

https://jsfiddle.net/xvgfx90q/

```
class People extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            peopleData: [],
            database: {}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchApi(); 
        this.syncDatabase();
    }

    // function that connects to external JSON file and parses it
    fetchApi() {... it sets peopleData state after promise has been resolved}

    // function called from PersonSection to pass it's state and update main state of People
    syncStates(data) {
        const newState = this.state;
        newState.database[data.id] = data;
        this.setState(newState); // <-- !! PERFORMANCE DROP HERE !!
        this.saveDatabase();
    }

    // connects to phone's DB and updates state with result of promise
    async syncDatabase() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem(this.state.DBKey).then((data) => {
            let newState = {};
            newState.database = JSON.parse(data);
            this.setState(newState);
        }).catch((error) => {
            return error;
        })
    }

    // saves current state to DB
    async saveDatabase() {
        AsyncStorage.setItem(this.state.DBKey, JSON.stringify(this.state.database));
    }


    renderTeams() {
        return Object.keys(this.state.peopleData).map((team) => {
            return (
                <TeamSection key={team} teamName={team} membersList={this.state.peopleData[team]}>
                    {this.renderPeople(team)}
                </TeamSection>
            )
        })
    }

    renderPeople(team) {
        return this.state.peopleData[team].map((people) => {
            return (
                <PersonSection
                    key={people.id}
                    data={people}
                    database={_.has(this.state.database, people.id) ? this.state.database[people.id] : false}
                    navigator={this.props.navigator}
                    syncStates={this.syncStates.bind(this)}
                 />
            )
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.wrapper}>
                <Options filterPeople={this.filterPeople.bind(this)} />
                {this.renderTeams()}
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}

class PersonSection extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            database: {
                id: this.props.data.id,
                name: this.props.data.name,
                favourites: this.props.database.favourites
            }
        }
    }

    // updates components state and sends it to parent component
    toggleFavourites() {
        const newState = this.state.database;
        newState.favourites = !newState.favourites;
        this.setState(newState);
        this.props.syncStates(this.state.database);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <View>
                <View>
                    <View>
                        <Text>{this.props.data.name}</Text>
                        <Text>{this.props.data.position}</Text>
                        <Text>{this.props.data.ext}</Text>
                    </View>
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.toggleFavourites()}>
                    { this.state.database.favourites
                        ? <Icon name="ios-star" size={36} color="#DAA520" />
                        : <Icon name="ios-star-outline" size={36} color="#DAA520" />}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
        )
    }

};

export default PersonSection;

React.render(<People />, document.getElementById('app'));`
```

Comment: How do you know this is true? `this.setState(newState); // <-- !! PERFORMANCE DROP HERE !!`

Comment: Does it always have that delay? or only when the list gets quite long? I ran into a similar performance issue and it went away when I used a <ListView>

Comment: also not sure why you have divs in your render `<div>hello</div>`

Comment: It just works perfectly fine when I remove this line. So passing state from childs to parent is fine, saving to db is fine, any animations are fine it just slows down when I leave this setState.

Comment: Don't worry about these <divs> - that's just my dirty marqup when I tried to simulate my react-native app in just react but decided to leave out as it is as that would consume too much time, general idea is about updating states. I've considered <ListView> but would it help me with my problem? Rendering is ok, just updating state is borking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a recommended way to do it, but basically you can just update the child state instead of the parent and passing it back down.

```
class People extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            peopleData: [],
            database: {}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchApi(); 
        this.syncDatabase();
    }

    // function that connects to external JSON file and parses it
    fetchApi() {... it sets peopleData state after promise has been resolved}

    // function called from PersonSection to pass it's state and update main state of People
    syncStates(data) {
        this.state.database[data.id] = data;
        this.saveDatabase();
    }

    // connects to phone's DB and updates state with result of promise
    async syncDatabase() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem(this.state.DBKey).then((data) => {
            let newState = {};
            newState.database = JSON.parse(data);
            this.setState(newState);
        }).catch((error) => {
            return error;
        })
    }

    // saves current state to DB
    async saveDatabase() {
        AsyncStorage.setItem(this.state.DBKey, JSON.stringify(this.state.database));
    }


    renderTeams() {
        return Object.keys(this.state.peopleData).map((team) => {
            return (
                <TeamSection key={team} teamName={team} membersList={this.state.peopleData[team]}>
                    {this.renderPeople(team)}
                </TeamSection>
            )
        })
    }

    renderPeople(team) {
        return this.state.peopleData[team].map((people) => {
            return (
                <PersonSection
                    key={people.id}
                    data={people}
                    database={_.has(this.state.database, people.id) ? this.state.database[people.id] : false}
                    navigator={this.props.navigator}
                    syncStates={this.syncStates.bind(this)}
                 />
            )
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.wrapper}>
                <Options filterPeople={this.filterPeople.bind(this)} />
                {this.renderTeams()}
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}

class PersonSection extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            database: {
                id: this.props.data.id,
                name: this.props.data.name,
                favourites: this.props.database.favourites
            }
        }
    }

    // updates components state and sends it to parent component
    toggleFavourites() {
        const newState = this.state.database;
        newState.favourites = !newState.favourites;
        this.setState(newState);
        this.props.syncStates(this.state.database);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <View>
                <View>
                    <View>
                        <Text>{this.props.data.name}</Text>
                        <Text>{this.props.data.position}</Text>
                        <Text>{this.props.data.ext}</Text>
                    </View>
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.toggleFavourites()}>
                    { this.state.database.favourites
                        ? <Icon name="ios-star" size={36} color="#DAA520" />
                        : <Icon name="ios-star-outline" size={36} color="#DAA520" />}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
        )
    }

};

export default PersonSection;

React.render(<People />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Just gave it a go but unfortunately it had no great impact on performance. I'll check ListView tomorrow tho.

Comment: I just updated my answer, its not recommended because it's mutating the parent state but it wont cause a re-render which is hindering performance and only updates the state of that specific child.

Comment: I've recoded to use ListView instead of Views and that resolved my problem. Thanks!